# php add line break between dynamic content

Tags: php, html

This is a rather silly question but here goes. So i'm outputting css stylesheets on my page, they come in bundled in an array like

```
 Array 
( 
 [0] => <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/application/resources/css/stylesheet1.css">
 [1] => <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/application/resources/css/stylesheet2.css">
 [2] =><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="/application/resources/css/stylesheet3.css">
 )
```

So I do:

```
<?php 
$css_elements = count($css);
for($i=0; $i < $css_elements; $i++) 
{
echo $css[$i];
}
?>
```

### and I get one giant bloc:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href=""><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href=""><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="">
```

### but I want something like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="">
```

how can I add a line break between style sheets without actually adding any spacing to the page I tried `<br>` and `/n` and neither of them worked.

Comment: What do you mean by adding a line break without adding any spacing to the page?

Answer (score 1):

echo $css[$i]."\r\n";

If you want also you can add `<P>` or `<br>`

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$css_elements = count($css);
for($i=0; $i < $css_elements; $i++) 
{
    echo $css[$i].'<br>';
}
```

OR:

```
 $css_elements = count($css);
    for($i=0; $i < $css_elements; $i++) 
    {
        echo $css[$i]."\r\n";
    }
```

Comment: the <br> version adds spacing to the page the \r\n one works fine but i swear i tried that and it didn't work just outputted the \n a bunch of times, ugh

Comment: @Edward probably because you enclosed it with single quotes instead of double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
 echo nl2br($css[$i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to had a end of line character at each iteration. There's a [constant](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php) for that in PHP, set for each system which is named `PHP_EOL`:

```
$css_elements = count($css);
for($i=0; $i < $css_elements; $i++) 
{
    echo $css[$i].PHP_EOL;
}
```